# ¿Como comprimir un archivo XML en ZIP en VBA Excel?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, zip

**Estoy intentando comprimir un archivo XML en un ZIP y estoy utilizando el código que se encuentra a continuación, pero me estoy topando con el siguiente error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Indica el erro sobre esta linea**

---

```
Shell.Namespace(zipFile).CopyHere (xmlFile)
```

---

**Codigo:**

```
 Sub CreateZipFile(BalanzaComprobacion As String)

    Dim zipFile As String           
    Dim xmlFile  As String         
    Dim Shell As Shell32.Shell

    zipFile = "C:\XML\" & BalanzaComprobacion & ".zip"
    xmlFile = "C:\XML\" & BalanzaComprobacion & ".xml"

    NewZip (zipFile)

    Shell.Namespace(zipFile).CopyHere (xmlFile)

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub NewZip(zipFile)

    Dim oFSO, arrHex, sBin, i, Zip
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    arrHex = Array(80, 75, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, _
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrHex)
        sBin = sBin & Chr(arrHex(i))
    Next
    With oFSO.CreateTextFile(zipFile, True)
        .Write sBin
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en que quieres usar una variable tipo `string` cuando lo que debes usar en `variant` para que el código funcione correctamente

```
 Sub CreateZipFile(BalanzaComprobacion As String)

    Dim zipFile As variant           
    Dim xmlFile  As variant         
    Dim Shell As Shell32.Shell

    zipFile = "C:\XML\" & BalanzaComprobacion & ".zip"
    xmlFile = "C:\XML\" & BalanzaComprobacion & ".xml"

    NewZip (zipFile)

    Shell.Namespace(zipFile).CopyHere (xmlFile)

End Sub
```

Así mismo debes recordar que si dejas la variables de esta manera

```
    Dim zipFile 
    Dim xmlFile
```

Es lo mismo que arriba.

**NOTA**: 
Probé ese código en una computadora con 64, por tanto quiero dejar la versión para 64 bits.

```
  Sub CreateZipFile(BalanzaComprobacion As String)

        Dim zipFile          
        Dim xmlFile     
        Dim myShell As Object

        zipFile = "C:\XML\" & BalanzaComprobacion & ".zip"
        xmlFile = "C:\XML\" & BalanzaComprobacion & ".xml"

        NewZip (zipFile)

        Set myShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        myShell.Namespace(zipFile).CopyHere (xmlFile)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Elbert ya funciona de esa manera